# Is there a way to change a label of one window from another window?

Tags: python, pyqt5

I've got some code that checks which checkboxes a user clicks. Those are then put into an array (aylm). Once the user clicks the book button, a small confirmation window pops up which says are you sure you want to book these rooms. In this confirmation window, I would like the label to say are you sure you want to book (aylm)? so that all the rooms and times selected can be seen by the user. I am not sure how to go about this since I'm using one main window which connects all the smaller windows together, which you can see below in the code.

```
class Ui_DialogBook(QtWidgets.QDialog, Ui_DialogBook):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Ui_DialogBook, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

class Ui_ViewAllRooms(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_ViewAllRooms):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Ui_ViewAllRooms, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.dialogBook = Ui_DialogBook()
        self.book_Button.clicked.connect(self.dialogBook.show)
        self.book_Button.clicked.connect(self.book_clicked)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def book_clicked(self):
        items = []
        for i in range(self.tableWidget.rowCount()):
            for j in range(self.tableWidget.columnCount()):
                item = self.tableWidget.item(i, j)
                if item.checkState() == QtCore.Qt.Checked:
                    items.append(item)

        for it in items:
            r = it.row()
            c = it.column()
            v, h = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(c).text(), self.tableWidget.verticalHeaderItem(r).text()
            self._checked_items.append([h, v])
            aylm = (self.checked_items())

        aylm_len = len(aylm)
        for nm in range (0, aylm_len):
            print (aylm[nm])

    def checked_items(self):
        return self._checked_items
```

The auto generated code from PyQt designer for the Ui_DialogBook is below:

```
class Ui_DialogBook(object):
    def setupUi(self, DialogBook):
        DialogBook.setObjectName("DialogBook")
        DialogBook.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(200, 150))

        self.invalidLogin_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(DialogBook)
        self.invalidLogin_label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 181, 71))
        self.invalidLogin_label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.invalidLogin_label.setObjectName("invalidLogin_label")
        self.no_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(DialogBook)
        self.no_button.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(110, 100, 75, 23))
        self.no_button.setObjectName("no_button")
        self.yes_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(DialogBook)
        self.yes_button.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 100, 75, 23))
        self.yes_button.setObjectName("yes_button")

        self.retranslateUi(DialogBook)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(DialogBook)

    def retranslateUi(self, DialogBook):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        DialogBook.setWindowTitle(_translate("DialogBook", "Dialog"))
        self.invalidLogin_label.setText(_translate("DialogBook", "Are you sure you would like \n to book:\n"))
        self.no_button.setText(_translate("DialogBook", "No"))
        self.yes_button.setText(_translate("DialogBook", "Yes"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    DialogBook = QtWidgets.QDialog()
    ui = Ui_DialogBook()
    ui.setupUi(DialogBook)
    DialogBook.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Ui_ViewAllRooms

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QDate, QTime, QDateTime, Qt

class Ui_ViewAllRooms(object):
    def setupUi(self, ViewAllRooms):

        ViewAllRooms.setObjectName("ViewAllRooms")
        ViewAllRooms.resize(671, 347)
        ViewAllRooms.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(671, 347))
        ViewAllRooms.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(671, 347))


        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(ViewAllRooms)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tableWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 100, 651, 181))
        self.tableWidget.setObjectName("tableWidget")
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(6)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(5)

        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderLabels("P1 P2 P3 P4 P5 P6".split())
        self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderLabels("C101 C214 C320 F04 E201".split())

        for i in range(self.tableWidget.rowCount()):
            for j in range(self.tableWidget.columnCount()):
                item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
                item.setFlags(item.flags() | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable)
                item.setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.Unchecked)
                self.tableWidget.setItem(i, j, item)
                self._checked_items = []

        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 290, 231, 41))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.book_Button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.book_Button.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(300, 290, 75, 23))
        self.book_Button.setObjectName("book_Button")
        self.backButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.backButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(590, 10, 75, 23))
        self.backButton.setObjectName("backButton")
        self.login_title = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.login_title.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(220, 10, 231, 38))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Gloucester MT Extra Condensed")
        font.setPointSize(25)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setItalic(False)
        font.setUnderline(True)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.login_title.setFont(font)
        self.login_title.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)
        self.login_title.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.login_title.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.login_title.setObjectName("login_title")
        self.date_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.date_label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(240, 70, 191, 21))
        self.date_label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.date_label.setObjectName("date_label")
        self.nextDayButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.nextDayButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(590, 70, 75, 23))
        self.nextDayButton.setObjectName("nextDayButton")
        ViewAllRooms.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(ViewAllRooms)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        ViewAllRooms.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.retranslateUi(ViewAllRooms)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(ViewAllRooms)        

    def retranslateUi(self, ViewAllRooms):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        ViewAllRooms.setWindowTitle(_translate("ViewAllRooms", "MainWindow"))
        item = self.tableWidget.verticalHeaderItem(0)
        item.setText(_translate("ViewAllRooms", "C101"))
        item.setToolTip("Hall")
        item = self.tableWidget.verticalHeaderItem(1)
        item.setText(_translate("ViewAllRooms", "C214"))
        item.setToolTip("Study Space")
        item = self.tableWidget.verticalHeaderItem(2)
        item.setText(_translate("ViewAllRooms", "C320"))
        item.setToolTip("Computer")
        item = self.tableWidget.verticalHeaderItem(3)
        item.setText(_translate("ViewAllRooms", "F04"))
        item.setToolTip("Mac Room")
        item = self.tableWidget.verticalHeaderItem(4)
        item.setText(_translate("ViewAllRooms", "E201"))
        item.setToolTip("Computer")
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(0)
        item.setText(_translate("ViewAllRooms", "P1"))
        item.setToolTip("8:55")
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(1)
        item.setText(_translate("ViewAllRooms", "P2"))
        item.setToolTip("9:55")
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(2)
        item.setText(_translate("ViewAllRooms", "P3"))
        item.setToolTip("11:15")
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(3)
        item.setText(_translate("ViewAllRooms", "P4"))
        item.setToolTip("12:15")
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(4)
        item.setText(_translate("ViewAllRooms", "P5"))
        item.setToolTip("2:00")
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(5)
        item.setText(_translate("ViewAllRooms", "P6"))
        item.setToolTip("3:15")
        __sortingEnabled = self.tableWidget.isSortingEnabled()
        self.tableWidget.setSortingEnabled(False)
        self.tableWidget.setSortingEnabled(__sortingEnabled)
        self.book_Button.setText(_translate("ViewAllRooms", "Book"))

        self.backButton.setText(_translate("ViewAllRooms", "Back"))
        self.login_title.setText(_translate("ViewAllRooms", "VIEW ALL ROOMS"))
        self.date_label.setText(_translate("ViewAllRooms", "Date:14 January 2019"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("ViewAllRooms", "Hover over a room number or period for\n"
"extra information"))
        self.nextDayButton.setText(_translate("ViewAllRooms", "Next Day"))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ViewAllRooms = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_ViewAllRooms()
    ui.setupUi(ViewAllRooms)
    ViewAllRooms.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[View All Rooms GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c1Gqr.png)

Comment: Publish the `class Ui_ViewAllRooms (object)`

Comment: I have added this now

Comment: 1.I(User) check the button for booking the room.2.After booking them,I push book-button3. the label of confirmation will popup.Do you want to change the label in accordance with the room number and datetime every time?

Comment: Yes so the user checks the boxes in the table (picture of table added above), then once the user has pressed book, the confirmation window should pop up and its label should change each time depending on what the user has selected. After I have figured this bit of code out, I will want to remove the checkbox that have been booked, to show that it has been booked, so the label should never really be the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it :

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore
from PyQt5.QtCore    import *
from PyQt5.QtGui     import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import * 


class Ui_DialogBook(object):
    def setupUi(self, DialogBook):
        DialogBook.setObjectName("DialogBook")
        DialogBook.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(200, 150))

        self.invalidLogin_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(DialogBook)
        self.invalidLogin_label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 181, 71))
        self.invalidLogin_label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.invalidLogin_label.setObjectName("invalidLogin_label")

        self.no_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(DialogBook)
        self.no_button.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(110, 100, 75, 23))
        self.no_button.setObjectName("no_button")

        self.yes_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(DialogBook)
        self.yes_button.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 100, 75, 23))
        self.yes_button.setObjectName("yes_button")

        self.retranslateUi(DialogBook)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(DialogBook)

    def retranslateUi(self, DialogBook):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        DialogBook.setWindowTitle(_translate("DialogBook", "Dialog"))
        self.invalidLogin_label.setText(_translate("DialogBook", "Are you sure you would like \n to book:\n"))
        self.no_button.setText(_translate("DialogBook", "No"))
        self.yes_button.setText(_translate("DialogBook", "Yes"))


class DialogBook(QtWidgets.QDialog, Ui_DialogBook):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(DialogBook, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.listWidget = QListWidget()

        self.grid = QGridLayout(self) 
        self.grid.addWidget(self.invalidLogin_label, 0, 0, 1, 2)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.listWidget,   1, 0, 1, 2)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.yes_button,   2, 0)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.no_button,    2, 1)        


class Ui_ViewAllRooms(object):
    def setupUi(self, ViewAllRooms):

        ViewAllRooms.setObjectName("ViewAllRooms")
        ViewAllRooms.resize(671, 347)
        ViewAllRooms.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(671, 347))
        ViewAllRooms.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(671, 347))


        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(ViewAllRooms)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tableWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 100, 651, 181))
        self.tableWidget.setObjectName("tableWidget")
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(6)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(5)

        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderLabels("P1 P2 P3 P4 P5 P6".split())
        self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderLabels("C101 C214 C320 F04 E201".split())

        for i in range(self.tableWidget.rowCount()):
            for j in range(self.tableWidget.columnCount()):
                item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
                item.setFlags(item.flags() | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable)
                item.setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.Unchecked)
                self.tableWidget.setItem(i, j, item)
                self._checked_items = []

        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 290, 231, 41))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.book_Button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.book_Button.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(300, 290, 75, 23))
        self.book_Button.setObjectName("book_Button")
        self.backButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.backButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(590, 10, 75, 23))
        self.backButton.setObjectName("backButton")
        self.login_title = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.login_title.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(220, 10, 231, 38))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Gloucester MT Extra Condensed")
        font.setPointSize(25)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setItalic(False)
        font.setUnderline(True)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.login_title.setFont(font)
        self.login_title.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)
        self.login_title.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.login_title.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.login_title.setObjectName("login_title")
        self.date_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.date_label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(240, 70, 191, 21))
        self.date_label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.date_label.setObjectName("date_label")
        self.nextDayButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.nextDayButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(590, 70, 75, 23))
        self.nextDayButton.setObjectName("nextDayButton")
        ViewAllRooms.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(ViewAllRooms)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        ViewAllRooms.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.retranslateUi(ViewAllRooms)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(ViewAllRooms)        

    def retranslateUi(self, ViewAllRooms):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        ViewAllRooms.setWindowTitle(_translate("ViewAllRooms", "MainWindow"))
        item = self.tableWidget.verticalHeaderItem(0)
        item.setText(_translate("ViewAllRooms", "C101"))
        item.setToolTip("Hall")
        item = self.tableWidget.verticalHeaderItem(1)
        item.setText(_translate("ViewAllRooms", "C214"))
        item.setToolTip("Study Space")
        item = self.tableWidget.verticalHeaderItem(2)
        item.setText(_translate("ViewAllRooms", "C320"))
        item.setToolTip("Computer")
        item = self.tableWidget.verticalHeaderItem(3)
        item.setText(_translate("ViewAllRooms", "F04"))
        item.setToolTip("Mac Room")
        item = self.tableWidget.verticalHeaderItem(4)
        item.setText(_translate("ViewAllRooms", "E201"))
        item.setToolTip("Computer")
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(0)
        item.setText(_translate("ViewAllRooms", "P1"))
        item.setToolTip("8:55")
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(1)
        item.setText(_translate("ViewAllRooms", "P2"))
        item.setToolTip("9:55")
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(2)
        item.setText(_translate("ViewAllRooms", "P3"))
        item.setToolTip("11:15")
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(3)
        item.setText(_translate("ViewAllRooms", "P4"))
        item.setToolTip("12:15")
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(4)
        item.setText(_translate("ViewAllRooms", "P5"))
        item.setToolTip("2:00")
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(5)
        item.setText(_translate("ViewAllRooms", "P6"))
        item.setToolTip("3:15")
        __sortingEnabled = self.tableWidget.isSortingEnabled()
        self.tableWidget.setSortingEnabled(False)
        self.tableWidget.setSortingEnabled(__sortingEnabled)
        self.book_Button.setText(_translate("ViewAllRooms", "Book"))

        self.backButton.setText(_translate("ViewAllRooms", "Back"))
        self.login_title.setText(_translate("ViewAllRooms", "VIEW ALL ROOMS"))
        self.date_label.setText(_translate("ViewAllRooms", "Date:14 January 2019"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("ViewAllRooms", "Hover over a room number or period for\n"
                                      "extra information"))
        self.nextDayButton.setText(_translate("ViewAllRooms", "Next Day"))


class ViewAllRooms(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_ViewAllRooms):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(ViewAllRooms, self).__init__(parent)

        self.setupUi(self)

        self.dialogBook = DialogBook()   #Ui_DialogBook()   # 

#        self.book_Button.clicked.connect(self.dialogBook.show)
        self.book_Button.clicked.connect(self.book_clicked)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def book_clicked(self):
        self._checked_items = []

#        items = []
        for i in range(self.tableWidget.rowCount()):
            for j in range(self.tableWidget.columnCount()):
                item = self.tableWidget.item(i, j)
                if item.checkState() == QtCore.Qt.Checked:
#                    items.append(item)
#                    r = it.row()
#                    c = it.column()
                    v = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(j).text()
                    h = self.tableWidget.verticalHeaderItem(i).text()

                    self._checked_items.append([h, v, self.tableWidget.item(i, j).text()])                    

        self.dialogBook.listWidget.clear()
        self.dialogBook.listWidget.addItems([ "{} {} {}".format(h, v, it) for h, v, it in self._checked_items])
        self.dialogBook.show()

        """            
        print("items->", items)            
        for it in items:
            r = it.row()
            c = it.column()
            v, h = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(c).text(), self.tableWidget.verticalHeaderItem(r).text()
            print("item---", self.tableWidget.item(r, c).text())
            self._checked_items.append([h, v])
            aylm = (self.checked_items())
        aylm_len = len(aylm)
        for nm in range (0, aylm_len):
            print (aylm[nm])
    def checked_items(self):
        return self._checked_items
        """

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    DialogBook = ViewAllRooms()

#    DialogBook = QtWidgets.QDialog()
#    ui = DialogBook()
#    ui.setupUi(DialogBook)

    DialogBook.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect, thank you so much! Also do you know how to make it so the user is not able to type in the table like how you've written 11111, 22222 etc?

Comment: @Taf  `self.tableWidget.setEditTriggers(QAbstractItemView.NoEditTriggers)`